# Syntactic sugar, simplify list initialisation like dictionary

Tags: c#, list, initialization

To initialize a `List<T>` you have to use individual type initializer for each element - something like this:

```
List<Cat> cats = new List<Cat>
{
    new Cat { Name = "Sylvester", Age = 8 },
    new Cat { Name = "Whiskers", Age = 2 },
    new Cat { Name = "Sasha", Age = 14 }
};
```

But for `Dictionary` you don't have to use the `KeyValuePair` initializer:

```
var numbers = new Dictionary<int, string>
{
    { 19, "nineteen" },
    { 23, "twenty-three" },
    { 42, "forty-two" }
};
```

Dictionary seems to be using the `public void Add(TKey key, TValue value)`, and list also has a method `public void Add(T item)`.

Is it possible to use a simplified initialisation for `List<T>` without individual initializers? Is it possible to `List<T>` to do it?

Comment: No, because List is generic, strong type

Comment: @viveknuna `Dictionary` is too.

Comment: No because dictionary is taking two values that happen to be simple types.  If you had a `Dictionary<int, Cat>` you'd have to do `{12, new Cat{ Name = "Kitty", Age = 3}}` as you have to create objects that match.  You could create your own list type that has a `Add(string name, int age)` and you'd be able to do it but that seems like overkill.

Comment: @juharr, found this example and way pretty puzzle about https://dotnetfiddle.net/HRuEpZ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `C# 6` you can also use [Extension `Add` methods in collection initializers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-6#extension-add-methods-in-collection-initializers) so that you don't need to create own collection type:

```
public static class CatListExtensions
{
   public static void Add(this List<Cat> list, string name, int age)
   {
      list.Add(new Cat {Name = name, Age = age});
   }
}
```

After adding such extension method you will be able to use it in collection initializer:

```
List<Cat> list = new List<Cat>
{
    {"Sylvester", 8},
    {"Whiskers", 2},
    {"Sasha", 14}
};
```

Answer (score 4):

The only way you can do that is if you create your own list type with a `Add(string name, int age)` method.

```
public class Cat
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

public class CatList : List<Cat>
{
    public void Add(string name, int age) => Add(new Cat { Name = name, Age = age });
}
```

Then you can run this code

```
var list = new CatList
{
    { "Sylvester", 8 },
    { "Whiskers", 2 },
    { "Sasha", 14 }
};

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(";", list.Select(c => $"{c.Name} is {c.Age}")));
```

But honestly I'm not sure it's worth it as you'd need to create custom collection types for each underlying type you want to store to be able to do this.

Another option is to initialize a list of value tuples and then translate it.

```
var list = new List<(string Name, int Age)>
{
    ( "Sylvester", 8 ),
    ( "Whiskers", 2 ),
    ( "Sasha", 14 )
}
.Select(x => new Cat { Name = x.Name, Age = x.Age })
.ToList();

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(";", list.Select(c => $"{c.Name} is {c.Age}")));
```

Comment: I agree it's  not worth it. it kill readability. 
But somehow writing simple example code, I has annoyed by having to write TheLongType_VeryClearName many time in a row. So I asked

Comment: @xdtTransform Another option is to initialize a list of value tuples and then translate it.  I've added that to the answer.

Comment: @juharr In C#6 [Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-6#extension-add-methods-in-collection-initializers) extension methods also can be used with collection initializers, so that there is no need to create own List type.

Comment: @IliarTurdushev I did not know it worked with extension methods, that's actually a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Collection initializers for `List` and `Dicitionary` use internally `Add` method, for `List` it is [`public void Add (T item);`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.add?view=netcore-3.1) and for dictionary it is [`public void Add (TKey key, TValue value);`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.add?view=netcore-3.1), so `Dictionary` collection initializer does not actually construct `KeyValuePair` to pass it to the `Add` method and this code:

```
var numbers = new Dictionary<int, string>
{
    { 19, "nineteen" },
    { 23, "twenty-three" },
    { 42, "forty-two" }
};
```

Is [translated](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0ATEBqAPgAQCYBGAWACh8AGAAn2JQG4L8BmOwmgYRoG8Kaguu3woaAWQAUASj4ChCgG4BDKDQB2AVwC2wGFADONALwaYAdxoARAJZgALjYjrVATwA8N9fbR1iVAD55QX5yBQVeGmIATl8AInUvGHsYGHU4mgBfNGDwyMJWePtzNPtXOHsAC1gYDOzciJoUQniAM2gyivMIOtzM5jChTIpMoA===) into something like this:

```
Dictionary<int, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();
dictionary.Add(19, "nineteen");
dictionary.Add(23, "twenty-three");
dictionary.Add(42, "forty-two");
```

You should be able to implement your own collection of `Cat`'s which will have `Add` method with all needed parameters so you can initialize it without passing the type name.